# Compilation failed, c++ program with static variable as private member variable

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu, static-members

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [undefined reference to static member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916759/undefined-reference-to-static-member-variable)
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class abc {

    private:
    static int a ;

    public:

    abc(int x) {
        a = x;
    }

    void showData() {
        cout<<"A = "<<a<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    abc a1(4);
    abc a2(5);

    a1.showData();
    a2.showData();

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this function on Ubuntu with GCC compiler. I get the following error.

```
/tmp/ccCKK2YN.o: In function `main':
static1.cpp:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `Something::s_nValue'
static1.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `Something::s_nValue'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilation failed.
```

Where as the following code runs fine

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Something
{
public:
    static int s_nValue;
};

int Something::s_nValue = 1;

int main()
{
    Something cFirst;
    cFirst.s_nValue = 2;

    Something cSecond;
    std::cout << cSecond.s_nValue;

    return 0;
}
```

Is this because Static member variables needs to initialized explicitly before accessing them via objects.Why so ?

Comment: http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/faq#toc4

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574407#12574407 - more specifically "static data members must be defined outside the class in a single translation unit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static int s_nValue;` doesn't allocate any storage to store the int, it just declares it.

You allocate somewhere in memory to store the variable with:

```
int Something::a=0;
```

Comment: What would just `int Something::a;` do?

Comment: Not sure if static members get auto-initialised or not: either undefined value, or 0 depending.

Comment: In general, all static storage variables (globals and the likes - including static members) are value-initialized - so to `0` in this case.

Comment: But I used constructor to initialize the static variable. Whats wrong with that ?

Comment: You don't have any constructors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

[The declaration of a static data member in the member list of a class is not a definition. You must define the static member outside of the class declaration, in namespace scope.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr038.htm)

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members).

In short, the static member needs to be initialized somewhere in a `.cpp` file so that the compiler allocates space for it. The declaration would look like this:

```
int abc::a = 0;
```

Comment: But I used constructor to initialize the static variable. Whats wrong with that ?

Comment: You can assign values to static variable in your constructor like you did, but you still need to define it in a `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because since static members are shared between all instances of a class, they need to be declared in one single place.

If you define the static variable inside the class declaration then each `include` to that file would have a definition to that variable (which is against to the `static` meaning).

Because of that you have to define the static members in the `.cpp`.